# Installing Refinery CMS on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I cannot get Refinery cms to install on my crappy Vista machine. I have followed all instructions on http://github.com/resolve/refinerycms but the bundler doesn't work because there is not gemfile (I have copied the gemfile from github but it fails at rmagick gem) and have also tried the command line instructions but it fails at rake db:setup.

I have tried installing all required gems myself but this makes no difference.

Can anyone give me a quick step by step on how to get it running? I have now completely removed ruby so can start afresh. I have the installers from rubyinstaller.org and have tried with both 1.8.7 and 1.9. I have mysql 5.1 installed.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If this is still a problem, try using the latest version of refinerycms (0.9.7.7) as there have been a lot of improvements to the installation process since then.

(also, please retag this question with refinerycms)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install RMagick yourself as it can`t be done by the bundler, have you tried this?

http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#win

Comment: Make sure you install ImageMagick first - rmagick is just a ruby front-end for that application.